# In C#, how do I add event handlers to an object based on names?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I'm am trying to add event handlers to 'myObject' based on the *name* of an event or events.
'myObject' has an event called 'MyEvent' and I have a public event handler called 'MyEventHandler' (which I don't need to get by name but do it below to get a MethodInfo).

This is what I have so far:

```
EventInfo eventInfo = myObject.GetType().GetEvent("MyEvent");
MethodInfo handlerInfo = GetType().GetMethod("MyEventHandler");

if (eventInfo != null && handlerInfo != null)
   eventInfo.AddEventHandler(
      this,
      Delegate.CreateDelegate(eventInfo.EventHandlerType, handlerInfo)
   );
```

I get this error:

> Error binding to target method.

Am I on the right track or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had success with this code:

```
eventInfo.AddEventHandler(this, Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(eventInfo.EventHandlerType.FullName), this, "MyEventHandler"));
```

Edit:
Added: eventInfoEventHandlerType.FullName so it's a little more dynamic based on the event handler type.

Comment: Almost, I combined your answer with the other answer that just disappeared (using 'myObject' instead of this for the first parameter). Thank you both.

Answer (score 0):

A more general approach that accepts **lambda** delegates also:

```
Eventinfo eventinfo= obj.GetType().GetEvent(eventName, Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);

eventinfo.AddEventHandler(obj, Delegate.CreateDelegate(eventinfo.EventHandlerType, Handler.Target, Handler.Method));
```

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23658733/how-do-i-bind-an-anonymous-action-as-new-event-handler-using-reflection)