# How do I bind an Anonymous action as new event handler using reflection

Tags: c#, winforms, events, reflection, datagridview

I am writing a number of unit tests for Windows Forms, and so far have been able to figure out how to set private controls' properties and invoke their methods, using Reflection. But I am stuck on how to associate an in-line lambda to attach itself to an event occurring on one of the controls, in this case the DataSourceChanged event of DataGridView.

```
public static void ObserveGrid(this Form form, string controlName, Action action)
{
    var controls = form.Controls.Find(controlName, true);
    if (controls.Any())
    {
        var control = controls[0] as DataGridView;
        if (control != null)
        {
            EventInfo ei = typeof(DataGridView).GetEvent("DataSourceChanged");
            if (ei != null)
            {
                ei.AddEventHandler(control, Delegate.CreateDelegate(ei.EventHandlerType, control, action.Method ));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I was hoping to call it like this:

```
var monitor = new Mutex();
form.ObserveGrid("dataGridView1",
    () =>
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Releasing mutex.");
        monitor.ReleaseMutex();
    });
var sw = new Stopwatch();
form.ClickButton("btnSearch", sw);
monitor.WaitOne();
sw.Stop();
```

During execution I get an error:

> Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security
>   transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type.

What am I doing wrong in this case?

**UPDATE:**

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120422/how-to-attach-event-handler-to-an-event-using-reflection?rq=1) great post, I have changed my Extensions class like so:

```
    public static void ObserveGrid(this Form form, string controlName, Action<object,object> action)
    {
        var controls = form.Controls.Find(controlName, true);
        if (controls.Any())
        {
            var control = controls[0] as DataGridView;
            if (control != null)
            {
                EventInfo ei = typeof(DataGridView).GetEvent("DataSourceChanged");
                if (ei != null)
                {
                    Delegate handler = ConvertDelegate(action, ei.EventHandlerType);
                    ei.AddEventHandler(control, handler);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static Delegate ConvertDelegate(Delegate originalDelegate, Type targetDelegateType)
    {
        return Delegate.CreateDelegate(
            targetDelegateType,
            originalDelegate.Target,
            originalDelegate.Method);
    }
```

However I get another error, this time about releasing the mutex from an non-synchronized thread:

> Releasing mutex.
>   System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException : 
>   Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>    ----> System.ApplicationException : 
>   Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code.

**UPDATE 2**

Swapping Mutex for SemaphoreSlim resolved the synchronization issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing:

First, the Extensions class:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    #region Public Methods and Operators

    public static Stopwatch ClickButton(this Form form, string controlName)
    {
        var controls = form.Controls.Find(controlName, true);
        if (controls.Any())
        {
            var control = controls[0] as Button;
            if (control != null)
            {
                MethodInfo mi = typeof(Button).GetMethod("OnClick", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
                var stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                mi.Invoke(
                    control,
                    new object[]
                    {
                        EventArgs.Empty
                    });
                return stopWatch;
            }
        }
        throw new ApplicationException("Control not found or of invalid Type");
    }

    public static Delegate ConvertDelegate(Delegate originalDelegate, Type targetDelegateType)
    {
        return Delegate.CreateDelegate(targetDelegateType, originalDelegate.Target, originalDelegate.Method);
    }

    public static object GetControlProperty<T>(this Form form, string controlName, string propertyName) where T : class
    {
        var controls = form.Controls.Find(controlName, true);
        if (controls.Any())
        {
            var control = controls[0];
            PropertyInfo pi = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName);
            return pi.GetValue(control, null);
        }
        throw new ApplicationException("Control not found or of invalid Type");
    }

    public static void ObserveControlEvents<T>(this Form form, string controlName, string eventName, Action<object, object> action) where T : class
    {
        var controls = form.Controls.Find(controlName, true);
        if (controls.Any())
        {
            var control = controls[0] as T;
            if (control != null)
            {
                EventInfo ei = typeof(T).GetEvent(eventName);
                if (ei != null)
                {
                    Delegate handler = ConvertDelegate(action, ei.EventHandlerType);
                    ei.AddEventHandler(control, handler);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void ObserveGrid(this Form form, string controlName, string eventName, Action<object, object> action)
    {
        var controls = form.Controls.Find(controlName, true);
        if (controls.Any())
        {
            var control = controls[0] as DataGridView;
            if (control != null)
            {
                EventInfo ei = typeof(DataGridView).GetEvent(eventName);
                if (ei != null)
                {
                    Delegate handler = ConvertDelegate(action, ei.EventHandlerType);
                    ei.AddEventHandler(control, handler);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void SetControlProperty<T>(this Form form, string controlName, string propertyName, object value) where T : class
    {
        var controls = form.Controls.Find(controlName, true);
        if (controls.Any())
        {
            var control = controls[0];
            PropertyInfo pi = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName);
            pi.SetValue(control, value, null);
        }
    }

    public static void SetFormProperty(this Form form, string controlName, object value)
    {
        var controls = form.Controls.Find(controlName, true);
        if (controls.Any())
        {
            var control = controls[0];
            PropertyInfo pi = typeof(Control).GetProperty("Text");
            pi.SetValue(control, value, null);
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Now, in my unit tests I can create the form, set values, trigger and observe the events:

```
[TestFixture]
public class FormsTests
{
    #region Public Methods and Operators

    [TestCase(null, null, null, 1000)]
    [TestCase("Kim", null, null, 500)]
    [TestCase("Kim", null, "Akers", 250)]
    [TestCase("Kim", "B", "Abercrombie", 100)]
    public void InsuredSearcherResponseTimeWithReflectionTest(string firstName, string middleName, string lastName, long milliseconds)
    {
        var monitor = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
        monitor.Wait();
        var form = new Insured();
        form.SetControlProperty<TextBox>("tbFirstName", "Text", firstName);
        form.SetControlProperty<TextBox>("tbMiddleName", "Text", middleName);
        form.SetControlProperty<TextBox>("tbLastName", "Text", lastName);
        form.ObserveControlEvents<DataGridView>(
            "dataGridView1",
            "DataSourceChanged",
            (sender, args) =>
            {
                Trace.WriteLine("Occured in delegate");
                monitor.Release();
            });
        Trace.WriteLine("Executing");
        var sw = form.ClickButton("btnSearch");
        monitor.Wait();
        sw.Stop();
        Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("Row count was {0} took {1}ms to process", form.GetControlProperty<DataGridView>("dataGridView1", "RowCount"), sw.ElapsedMilliseconds));
        Assert.IsTrue(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds < milliseconds);
    }

    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void TestFixtureSetup()
    {
        var monitor = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
        monitor.Wait();
        var form = new Insured();
        form.ObserveControlEvents<DataGridView>(
            "dataGridView1",
            "DataSourceChanged",
            (sender, args) =>
            {
                Trace.WriteLine("Occured in delegate");
                monitor.Release();
            });
        form.ClickButton("btnSearch");
        monitor.Wait();
    }
}
```

I hope this helps someone as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following definition below:

```
public static class Xtd
{
    public static void AddEventEasy(this object component, EventInfo eventInfo, Delegate eventAction)
    {
        Delegate ConvertDelegate(Delegate originalDelegate, Type targetDelegateType)
        {
            return Delegate.CreateDelegate(
                targetDelegateType,
                originalDelegate.Target,
                originalDelegate.Method);
        }

        eventInfo.AddEventHandler(component, ConvertDelegate(eventAction, eventInfo.EventHandlerType));
    }
}
```